# mutiply x axis by a factor

Tags: plotting

i have this equation

```
 (3.47471*10^31 (3.525 + 3.83003*10^-10 F^2))/(0.5814 + 
 9.89982*10^-10 F^2 + 1.05946*10^-20 F^4)
```

i can plot it simply.
however i want to multiply x and y axes by a desired factor,
i can do it for y axis, how can i modify the x axis?

```
Plot[Evaluate[{10^-9 \[Kappa]e}], {F, 0, 2 10^17}, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
FrameLabel -> {"B/\[Rho](G.\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \
\(2\)]\).\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), \(-1\)]\))", 
"(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \
\(e\)]\))\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \
\(9\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-1\)]\).\!\ 
(\*SuperscriptBox[\
\(s\), \(-1\)]\))"}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, (FontSize -> 15)], 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[LineLegend[{Style[
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \(i\)]\)", "Times", 15, 
  Bold]}], {0.85, 0.85}], 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are perhaps more elegant answers, but let's say you want to scale the x-axis by 10^17.  Then this would do that:

```
equation1[
  F_] := (3.47471*10^31 (3.525 + 3.83003*10^-10 F^2))/(0.5814 + 
    9.89982*10^-10 F^2 + 1.05946*10^-20 F^4);
Plot[10^-9 equation1[10^17*F], {F, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameLabel -> {"10^17 * B/\[Rho](G.\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \
\(2\)]\).\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), \(-1\)]\))", 
   "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \
\(e\)]\))\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \
\(9\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-1\)]\).\!\ 
   (\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(-1\)]\))"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, (FontSize -> 15)], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Style[
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Kappa]\), \(i\)]\)", "Times", 15, 
      Bold]}], {0.85, 0.85}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed]}]
```

This returns this graph: 
[image]

Comment: thank you very much, it did help.